# $\sigma\{A_i \cap B_j\}=\sigma\{\{A_i\} \cup \{B_j\}\}=\sigma\{\sigma\{A_i\} \cup \sigma\{B_j\}\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{A_1,A_2,...,A_m\}$ and $\{B_1,B_2,...,B_n\}$ be two partitions of $\Omega$. I am searching a proof of the following facts:

a) $\{A_i \cap B_j\}$ is a partition of $\Omega$.

b) $\sigma\{A_i \cap B_j\}=\sigma\{\{A_i\} \cup \{B_j\}\}=\sigma\{\sigma\{A_i\} \cup \sigma\{B_j\}\}$

I already managed to proof a) and the inclusions $\sigma\{A_i \cap B_j\}\subseteq\sigma\{\{A_i\} \cup \{B_j\}\}$,$\sigma\{\{A_i\} \cup \{B_j\}\}\subseteq\sigma\{\sigma\{A_i\} \cup \sigma\{B_j\}\}$,

But I have problems to prove:
$\sigma\{\sigma\{A_i\} \cup \sigma\{B_j\}\}\subseteq\sigma\{A_i \cap B_j\}.$

Note: here, $\sigma \{ A_i \}$ refers to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{ A_i \}$ in $\Omega$; ditto for $\sigma\{ B_j \}$, $\sigma \{ A_i \cap B_j \}$, etc.

Please, someone help me with this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. I don't know what you are meaning with $\sigma$. Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri: Sigma algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that for every $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, where $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is the power set of $\Omega$, one has $$\sigma\{ \sigma \{ \mathcal{A} \} \} = \sigma\{ \mathcal{A} \}.$$

Comment: Oh, but this would be used to proved the whole equality in another way, right?

Comment: @JBr Yes, you would use this to show that each of the two containments you have proved also hold in the other direction, thereby proving that they are all equal.